# Failed to guess the correct output

Tags: c

Basically I am a Java programmer, and not very well know about pointers in C.

so,

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main( ){
    char*______Time______ = "world";
    printf("%s",_____Time_____);
    return 0;
}
```

I guess the output here should be: world  ?

Is something spooky here which I should know?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A typo: "______ Time______" (space in the middle)

Comment: You are also using the wrong double quotes

Comment: So when you saved this as a file, and compiled it, and ran it ... what happened?

Comment: @meaning-matters This question was asked in a certain Question paper.Just saw it.

Comment: The variable used in `printf()` is different from the one you defined earlier - it contains different numbers of underscores. BTW: You can easily try out such code snippets on an online IDE, like http://ideone.com/

Comment: spooky _yes_ ,`__` before and after some variable name should be avoided to avoid conflict with predefined macros.

Comment: @Dayalrai Not my coding style, was asked in some Question paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should print "world", yes.

It looks a bit like it's trying to play with the GCC built-in preprocessor symbol `__TIME__`, but of course it's spelled wrong to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I expect to see `world`, but your shell might then see that the last command ended without a newline and it might add something to signify that before starting its prompt on a fresh line.

Answer (score 1):

> and not very well know about pointers in C

A pointer is a variable which points to a specific address in the memory.

In this case, it points to the first letter of `"world"`, which is then printed by `printf()` all until NUL (automatically inserted at the end of strings).

So, answering your question: yes, the output will be "world".